# Replacing the explorer pane in windows?

Tags: windows, windows-shell, windows-explorer

When a user puts in a CD and autoruns, I want to "browse" the CD but I want to do some extra processing of the disk contents.  If I wanted to replace the ListView in windows explorer with one of my own, how would I start?  What terms should I search for to find out how to do this.  I want to get the treeview part that explorer provides,  and all the shell interaction, I just want to hide the extra extension on the end of the file names (.pgp) and show the icons for the files as if they weren't encrypted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your best option is use a [Shell Namespace extension](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Shell_namespace) like the GMail Drive shell

[image]

see this links

- [An almost complete Namespace Extension Sample](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/NamespaceExtImpl.aspx)
- [Create Namespace Extensions for Windows Explorer with the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188741.aspx)
- [Tips in Writing Namespace Extensions (I) - Implements Subfolder](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/TipsInNSE_SubFld.aspx)
- [Tips in Writing Namespace Extensions (II) - Implement Create and Delete Object Operations](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/NSExtAddDelFld.aspx)

Bye.